# How can I correctly provision an Xamarin Forms iOS app with (or without) a ShareExtension?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, provisioning, share-extension

I've had hours and hours of problems with **Xamarin Forms iOS provisioning** for my app **with and without** a **ShareExtension**.

I have had it working in the past with various combinations and permutations of configuring simulator/device/debug/release/certs/ids/auto or manual provisioning...etc. which I didn't record at the time, but it is very fickle and unpredictable and there are a large number of moving parts.

As such the following is a systematic record of the steps I've taken with questions when things have behaved in unexpected ways and my app hasn't run or deployed correctly.

**NOTE:** The following steps are for **development** but if I can get dev running, I will then continue to update this question for the **distribution** process.

The 3 main elements and their interaction that causes me most confusion are below:

1. Online **Apple Developer Portal**
2. **MacOS** with Xcode and keychain
3. **Windows Visual Studio Xamarin**

**STEPS TAKEN**

**A) DELETE EVERYTHING FOR A FRESH START**

I deleted all my certificates, identifiers and profiles from the above 3 (with the exception of the main app id which is in the app store and couldn't be deleted). For the physical devices I removed via:

- Xcode
- VS (Win)
- relevant folder locations on Win and Mac
- keychain

**B) CREATE A DEV CERT, AUTO PROVISION, RUN THE APP**

- In visual studio login to my Apple account via Options -> Apple Accounts
- Then View details -> Create certificate

**Outcome**: This works fine. The new cert appears on Windows, Mac and on the Apple Dev Portal. The app runs successfully with auto provisioning.

However, no profiles can be seen in the online Apple Dev Portal - why? - **UPDATE**: They now appear around 30 mins after they were created

**C) ADD A SHARE EXTENSION**

- Add **ShareExtension** project and reference it to my main app.
- Use Automatic Provisioning

**Outcome**:

- Auto Provisioning gives: "Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available.". As a result I go into the Apple Dev Portal and manually create an ID, then retry Auto Provisioning, which is now successful. Try to run the app again but: app runs ok, but share extension can't be seen.

I have double checked:

- Main app has ShareExtension reference
- Main app info.plist has:
  `<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key><string>com.apple.share-services</string>`
- App group is set in VS for both projects and both App IDs in online portal

What is going on here?

**---UPDATE---**

**D) TRY MANUAL PROVISIONING INSTEAD**

I did the following:

- Created two manual provisions, one for container and one for extension
- As Visual Studio Apple Account didn't reflect these, I downloaded the provisions from the portal, put them in the relevant Windows folder and now they appear
- Tried to build:

[image: Manual Provisioning problems]

What is happening here?

- Why is the error about **Auto** Prov, when I have clearly set it to **Manual** Prov
- Why is the 2nd error about the profile not found when it shows in above drop-down, and in the portal that it very clearly exists?

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried using Visual Studio 2022 to finish an iOS development process but cannot reproduce your stepD. The following is the main step:

**1. Create App ID for container and extension, Create an AppGroup ID**

*This is for my container, with App Group enabled.*

[image]

*This is for my extension App ID, also enable the same App Group.*

[image]

**2. Create certificate and profiles**

You could create a iOS development certificate in Visual Studio or in Apple Dev Portal. Then you could find it in your Certificates.

[image]

**3.Generate your profiles for both container and extension.** (Remember to register your physical device in **Devices**, and in your profiles, includes your device on which your app is installed)

*This is for my container with the container's App ID*

[image]

*this is for my extension with the extension's App ID*

[image]

**4. In Visual Studio, select the proper provisioning file.**

Before this step, also download the provisioning files from the portal as VS does not automatically download them. Put them in the relevant Windows folder.

This is for my container, with the certificate and the provisioning file

[image]

This is for my extension:

[image]

Also, my info.plist for container and extension:

[image]
[image]

**5. Pair to mac and run on your device**

[image]

Now the App could install on your device~

Comment: By the way, both of the container and extension should generate a profile

Comment: Thanks for your reply Liqun, please see my updated step **D)** above.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your stepD. Clean your project and your bin / obj  folder. Restart your VS, Xcode... was it fixed now?

Comment: Can I check, are you using VS for Mac or VS for Windows?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Well, it's a little bit tedious. I totally agree with you that there 
 are a lot of details that might cause the unpredictable results. I hope my answer makes sense

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. But I think the problem lies with the unreliability of Visual Studio and the fact that VS is not behaving the way it should, and producing incorrect results. I tried following your steps, cleared bin/obj, profiles once more, created the dev profiles manually. Now in the **Apple Accounts -> View Details -> Provisioning Profiles** window I can see the Provisioning profiles correctly. However, now those same profiles are not appearing in the **Manual Provisioning -> Provisioning Profile** dropdown list.

Comment: In the meantime I think I have found a solution that is working for me for now at least. Please see my Answer post. And thanks for your help. I will upvote your answer, because what you say does make sense, and if VS is working as it should, then your solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

After much pain, I have finally stumbled upon a combination of steps that seems to work. Given the unpredictable and what seems to be buggy nature of VS, I cannot guarantee that this will work for everyone, or even guarantee that it will even work for me again for my next build, but it has been working for the past 12 hours or so over several builds and deployments. I can only pray that it continues to work.

Anyway, here are keypoints that I used to get it working:

- Follow my step **A)** above and delete everything as often as possible. New certs and profiles in the Portal tend to accumulate after a while, possibly when creating via the Portal, Xcode and VS, so it's good to remove everything every so often and start from afresh.
- **VS for Mac** is I believe a much cut-down and less capable version of **VS for Windows**. As such when doing development, **VS Windows** is a far better tool, if you can get around development provisioning. I struck upon a combination where I created the Cert in VS Windows (this is preferable to creating in the Portal because it avoids having to download the cert and ensure it is installed correctly on your local machine), and used Automatic provisioning for debug that seemed to work for me. It didn't work for a while, nor did manual provisioning, but somehow for now its working.
- Once the app is stable in debug mode, and you want to deploy to App Store Connect:

  a) manually create your distribution certs on Xcode, and create profiles in the portal

  b) move your code onto VS Mac

  c) build and archive using the new distr profiles

  d) Goto **Xcode** -> **Window** -> **Organizer**

  e) Locate your archive and click **Distribute App**

  f) From here the wizard will guide you again into selecting relevant profiles for distribution for both container and ext and give you a lot of feedback on the upload process until the upload is complete.

Anyway, once again, no guarantees that will work for all, but it's working for me now.

Cheers!